# RecyclerView: Change and apply padding after layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView` and I want to change the `padding`, because I want the first item centered on the screen.
Because the size of the items are variable, I need to calculate the padding at `runtime`. 
i.e. like this:

```
+--------------------------+
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|           Text1  Text2  T|
|                          |
~                          ~
|                          |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
```

For this, I use an onLayoutChangeListener:

```
recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(object : View.OnLayoutChangeListener {
        override fun onLayoutChange(v: View?, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int, oldLeft: Int, oldTop: Int,
                                    oldRight: Int, oldBottom: Int) {
            recyclerView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this)

            // Use width of first child to calculate
            val childAt = recyclerView.layoutManager?.getChildAt(0)
            childAt?.let {
                val padding = calculateHorizontalPadding(it.width)
                recyclerView.setPadding(padding, recyclerView.paddingTop, padding,
                        recyclerView.paddingBottom)

                recyclerView.invalidate()
                recyclerView.requestLayout()
            }
        }
    })
```

It seems that the `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` calls have no effect.
Is there any other suggestion to calculate the `padding` dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this two ways.

First, you set a padding_start of your recyclerview. I'm not sure if this could work.
Second, on your adapter, check if the item on the onBindViewHolder is the first one. If so, place a paddling on the item view and calculate the center of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the first item width of recycler item in this way:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (position == 0) {
            holder.itemView.post {
                Log.v("__DEBUG", "onBind holder.itemView.width = ${holder.itemView.width}")
                Log.v("__DEBUG", "onBind holder.itemView.left = ${holder.itemView.left}")
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that even if I find out the padding in the view holder, I have to update the padding which does not seem to work.